# C# Detecting a Click in WndProc and calling a function after click happened

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to detect a **click** and preform calling a function only after the click actually happened.

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    //Detect a Click
    if (m.Msg == 0x210 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 513){
        lastClick = DateTime.Now;
        clickedHappened();
        Debug.Print("Click Detected!");
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);

}

private void clickedHappened(){
    MessageBox.Show("Click Already Happened");
}
```

I think that **WndProc** happens way before the actual click takes place.
I was wondering if there was a way to solve this with out using a **timer**?  or `sleep(400)`;

The only solution I can come up with is using a **timer**, but I want to get rid of some of my existing timers.  It seems that the click actually happens 200 - 350 ms after it was detected in **WndProc**.

Comment: WndProc is called hundreds of times even when you move the mouse over the form. Why can't you use the `MouseDown` event?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am moving a control around on the screen, I have 1 control per tab, after click is detected, I move it then switch tabs to the next control.   There is no way to reach it's own onClick event.  So I just detect the last mouse event and move it there.  But it seems that WndPos is moving way to fast and it's switching tabs before the click actually happens.

Comment: The control I am moving, I am moving it blindly, I cant reach it's own MouseEvents or Click Events. Mainly because it's layered into a browser control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WndProc is short for Window Procedure, its the procedure that handles everything for the window, drawing, mouse capture, keyboard capture, resizing...

There are also several ways you can capture the mouse for varying results

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch(m.Msg)
    {
         case 0x201:
           //left button down
           break;
          case 0x202:
           clickedHappened(); //left button up, ie. a click
           break;
         case 0x203:
           //left button double click
           break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

The thing is, windows forms in C# already handles all of these for you and from the WndProc, fires events there is no real need to handle WndProc yourself for this type of thing.

For a full list of mouse notification messages, see [MSDN: Mouse Input Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and for a list of all wndproc messages, see [MSDN System Defined Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_defined)

Comment: This does not seem to work at all.. Replacing clickedHappened() with Debug.Print("Clicked happened")  produces no results.

Comment: i would assume it is because you didnt use `[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]` which i just added in

Comment: I left that part in there from the original question.  I put that in there so when I do a code analyze it does not give me error messages.  Just copy and pasted to make sure.. but using Debug.Print("Click Happened")  Still no joy.. I am running in debug mode and I am not getting any messages from this statement.

Comment: i got the code originally when i was using this from MSDN, and this is still the example microsoft give now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx

Comment: It seems that I am clicking in a non client area so I can't use 0x201, 0x202, and ox203 they simply don't work..  It only works when the parent is notified using WM_PARENTNOTIFY or 0x210 and then looking for the param of the button down or 513,  Button Up or 514 does not work because I assume the parent is not notified?  I might be totally wrong on this.. wndProc is still very new to me..

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can handle WM_LBUTTONUP message that occured after click.
You can do it like this:

```
const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP)
    {               
        clickedHappened();
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```